# Taking serial string in from redpark cable

Tags: ios, string

I am taking in serial data from a redpark cable from an arduino. I am receiving data in a string in this form 12x13x14x15x16 with x separating the data. I want to know how to show the data coming in separately. So I can have 5 text boxes in the app showing each value individually.

Comment: Is your question really about how to split the string `12x13x14x15x16` into five separate strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question really has nothing to do with the arduino or red park cables, but actually is a question about how to split a string based on a delimiter, then all you need is:

```
NSString *data = @"12x13x14x15x16";
NSArray *parts = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"x"];
```

The array with have the 5 strings `@"12"`, `@"13"`, etc.